# Convert from British coordinates to standard WGS84 nmea

Tags: c#, windows, gps, coordinates, nmea

I was posting similar post already. And I did get an answer in theory but I really need somone to help me.

So I am using this [EXAMPLE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13577/GPS-Deriving-British-Ordnance-Survey-Grid-Referenc) for testing my GPS. What I want to do is how to get standard decimal values like 56,322415 for latitude and longitude.
Because now I am getting 5304,254 value.

I need it in this form because I will use this for Google maps.

Can you check code and tell me what should I left out or how to convert it to WGS84 format.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is the picture that is explaining what I see when I run the program
[image]

And this is the one that is one the codeproject page:

[image]

EDIT 2:

So when I use [THIS CONVERTER](http://www.csgnetwork.com/gpscoordconv.html) to see what decimal values I need to get when I have degrees I don't get the same values.

This is the value that I should get :

[image]

And this is the value that I get in the program:

> 46.64662666666667

Any idea why I can't get same conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following line in the ParseNMEA function is the one that does the conversion from WGS84 to the British Ordinance Survey coordinates:

```
return Transform(deciLat, deciLon, height);
```

so if you remove that line and just use deciLat and deciLon values, you should be fine...

**Addition after question update:**

The code you're referring to does not take local number formats into account, so if this goes wrong, it might be because of erroneous decimal symbol matching.

You can use the following functions to do the conversion, presuming the input is always in the invariant culture (with decimal points):

```
string[] arrLon = strLon.Split(new char[]{'°', '"'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
double dblLon = double.Parse(arrLon[0]) + double.Parse(arrLon[1], new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()) / 60;
double deciLon = arrLon[2] == "E" ? dblLon : - dblLon;
```

**Additional info:**

NumberFormatInfo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx

Comment: Hi, I have tried what you have said and when I remove part of the code when it is calling transform method I don't get any of the info. Have you tried to remove it? If you have managed to do this please let me know what part have you changed.

Comment: Hi denonth, this falls under very basic programming skills, so I'm not sure SO is the right place to learn about this, but the Transform function returns true if all goes well and so should the ParseNMEA function. I haven't downloaded and run the code, but you should `return true;` instead of the `return Transform(...`for the functions to run properly.

Comment: Hi, I have tried it already yesterday. I'll run trough the code.

Comment: If that is not enough to get the values in the format you expect, there is probably something wrong with the format of the source data (the Nlat and Nlon values and possibly even before that). Make sure you check them in debug mode or by printing them out or so. Even if there are differences in the seperator characters (both the decimal and the degrees symbols), the parsing function will fail.

Comment: When I am debugging I am getting some weird values. Funny thing is that on the picture on the codeproject site is right format that I need. Isn't that strange?

Comment: Is there maybe a problem because of 64bit version of windows?

Comment: I have edited some of the question above so you can see what am I talking about

Comment: Thank you Dirk I'll try your code. But this is for longitude right? Shouldn't there be 'double deciLon = arrLon[2] == "W" ? dblLon : - dblLon;' when we are checking longitude? Or it should be E?

Comment: Dirk thank you so much! I really did get in the decimal values. I have updated my question because I think something with converting is wrong. At least I think so. I am not getting the right value. I mean format is right but value isn't. Check it out

Comment: Hi denonth, my guess is you made a copy/paste error and are now using the longitude minutes to calculate the latitude value. Again I urge you to look into the debugging features of your dev environment so that you can better investigate the source of the problem that you are experiencing.

Comment: Oh, and please try to learn from the answers, rather than copy/pasting them; it will benefit you in the long run and it reinforces my feeling that I did something useful :-)

Comment: Hi Dirk, I must say big big thank you for resolving my problem. And yes I agree I actually have mixed some variables from lat and long. Honestly I am looking in this code all day and sometimes error is in front of me and I can't see it :) Anyway thank you again. And yes you did a something useful!

Comment: Well, that is something I can relate to, I can't count the hours I've been looking at a bug without seeing it :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problems are now solved, I do know that there were issues caused by different local number formatting which were raised and resolved in one of the comments:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13577/GPS-Deriving-British-Ordnance-Survey-Grid-Referenc?msg=2106791#xx2106791xx

If you simply want decimal values for lat and lon, I guess you can throw the entire thing away now and just use the solution provided by Dirk! =o)

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, yes you were right. Dirk solution did work for me. Thank you for your time