# how to change culture info on the string or double

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, format, cultureinfo

I want to change CultureInfo of double or the string.

For example I get double value from the code in format like 3015.0

I don't know in what unit is this but I need value in the meters and these are not in the meters because I am on the altitude of cca.100m

I have tried: `double.Parse(test, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hr-HR"));`

and `double.Parse(test, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo());`

but nothing is a right format what I need.

Any idea what I can do? This is windows form C# application if this is important. Framework 4.0

**EDIT**:

As you can see on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556435/convert-from-british-coordinates-to-standard-wgs84-nmea) I had a similar problem before and it was solved with culture info. Problem is that on picture 1 are the values that I get and on the picture 2 are the real values that I need to get ( when I say real I mean in the right format) I think that problem is in the culture somewhere as on my previously question I had problem with decimal values).

Comment: hi, actually I was sure that this was right solution, but let me tell you what the problem is. I get this value of 3000 or 2729 as a altitude. When I convert it I get value of 80-90 meters which is not correct as I am on altitude of cca. 230m. That means that this is not the right formula :) or I am getting something wrong. I used formula value= 0.03048 * altitude and it is giving me this value that I wrote. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not related to Culture info.

Looks like you are getting a measurement in feet while you are expecting it to be in meters. In fact, `100 meters = 328.08399 feet` and your measurements might be in 10 feets i.e `3015.0 = 301.5 feet` (some GPS receivers do not support floats or doubles and therefore return only integers multiplied by 10 to have one decimal accuracy)

If you are using a cheap GPS receiver than this is expected as the accuracy is not that great (this would explain why you are getting 3015.0 instead of 3280)

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Yeah, probably the height is given in a device specific unit.

Comment: everything is correct what you have said. So the formula is to convert feet to meters and divide with 10

Comment: hi, actually I was sure that this was right solution, but let me tell you what the problem is. I get this value of 3000 or 2729 as a altitude. When I convert it I get value of 80-90 meters which is not correct as I am on altitude of cca. 230m. That means that this is not the right formula :) or I am getting something wrong. I used formula `value= 0.03048 * altitude` and it is giving me this value that I wrote. Any idea?

Comment: I see, but doing `3000 * 0.3048` gives you `914.4` which is roughly `91 meters`. Are you sure you using the correct Ellipsoid height?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with CultureInfo but with unit conversion. Probably you will have to do a unit convertion. Are you sure that the number is not 301.5? This would probably mean that the altitue is given in feet.

```
double altitudeMeters = 0.3048 * altitudeFeet;
```

Comment: I am sure that is in 3005.0 example... I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

The setting of the current culture will not convert units for you.  It only affects the formatting of numbers (for example, some cultures use a comma instead of a period for the decimal point).  You'll have to do the units conversion yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`double.Parse` will simply convert the string into a number. It doesn't do unit conversions. The different culture information is for when there is a decimal comma (e.g. French) etc.

You will have to build some logic into your application to convert the number from what looks like feet to meters. If you can be sure that the data is always going to be in the "wrong" format then a simple feet to meters (1 foot = 0.3048 meters) conversion will work. Given that this is a GPS device you might be able to assume this.

If the numbers can be in any format then you will need to analyse the number and if it's outside the sensible range convert it. However, this will fail if someone enters "100". Is this metres or feet?

To ensure you get the right units you will either have to have the user select the units on a separate control or include the units in the input string. If you do the latter then you'll need to get into parsing the string to see if it contains a units string, stripping it off, parsing the number and the string and then doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Altitude comes from $GPGGA string which indicates the units being used. What does the $GPGGA string look like?

see http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gga

if you look at the raw data in the string you will know if you are collecting the right numbers and their units

Alex

Comment: having received a sample of a $GPGGA string from Denonth "$GPGGA,195647.000,4633.3942,N,01538.7926,E,1,05,2.3,300.1,M,43.3,M,,0000*5D" I would say that his GPS is reporting ~ 300m altitude

Comment: as to why he is seeing this as ~3000 in his software - perhaps this is a culture effect